# How to add a image style to an image in a template file?

Tags: theming

I need to change these lines (belong to a tpl.php file) to include a image style called "adaptative_image_style" to the generated image.

```
<?php print l(theme('image', $image_attributes), $ad['url'], $link_attributes); ?>
```

I think I should use the function to theme_image_style($variables) instead but not sure how to implement it.

Based in Clive's answer I get it working with this code:

```
  <?php 
  $image_attributes['style_name'] = 'adaptative_image_style';
  print l(theme('image', $image_attributes), $ad['url'], $link_attributes); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) has it pretty much covered but here's an example if you're struggling:

```
$style_vars = array(
  'style_name' => $style_name,
  'path' => $image_path,
  'alt' => $alt_text
);

$image = theme('image_style', $style_vars);

$link = l($image, $url, array('html' => TRUE));
```